# Git CHECKOUT working only through gutter indicators (on VSC)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, diff, checkout

I 've just started working with GIT and Vcs and I have a bit of an issue.

As you can see from the pictures everytime I checkout any commit all I get from VCS is a comparison between the different snapshots through the diff tool.

How can I simply have the commits displayed in a "clean" way without the gutter indicators?
In other words,the first picture is the latest commit.how can I see the previous like that, without the comparison?

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

Comment: I don't see anything being checked out in the screenshots?

Comment: You have uncommitted changes (some deletion) which are not in conflict on branches which you are switching to. Just drop uncommitted changes or commit them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you can see at the bottom head is not pointing at master anymore

Comment: @MarekR I did commited everything.I'm not actually working on one single code, I'm simply writing different codes for a course I'm doing

My point is that I'd like to go back to previous commits without having to compare to the current one I'm working on